# Onsignal app id invalid

Tags: android

I am trying to impliment onsignal push notifications in am android app project i  get error when i open app says invalid app id please help

Error log

```
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    OneSignal AppId format is invalid.
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    Example: 'b2f7f966-d8cc-11e4-bed1-df8f05be55ba'
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: uuid == null
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID.java:182)
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at com.onesignal.OSUtils.initializationChecker(OSUtils.java:62)
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at com.onesignal.OneSignal.init(OneSignal.java:491)
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at com.onesignal.OneSignal.init(OneSignal.java:467)
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at com.onesignal.OneSignal.access$000(OneSignal.java:79)
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at com.onesignal.OneSignal$Builder.init(OneSignal.java:283)
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at com.mytest.test.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:24)
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1037)
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6422)
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:229)
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887)
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
11-08 18:50:58.831 15128 15128 E   OneSignal                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
11-08 18:50:59.721 2622 3256 E     Watchdog                                     !@Sync 1206 [11-08 18:50:59.734]
```

Build.gradle

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mytest.test"

        // TODO: Please update the OneSignal ID below to yours!
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "955e2312-8a7f-45c8-9418-c58dc24b8632",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // OneSignal requires at least version 7.0.0 of GMS but the newest version is recommend.
    // Required for OneSignal, even if you have added FCM.
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'

    // Required for geotagging
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'


    // play-services-analytics is only needed when using 8.1.0 or older.
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

compile files('libs/OneSignalSDK.jar')
}
```

Any idea what's wrong? 
I am trying to impliment onsignal push notifications in am android app project i  get error when i open app says invalid app id please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this picture:

[image]

And see bellow url :

[Troubleshooting Android](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/troubleshooting-android#section-onesignal-dependencies)

Insert your Sender ID here `REMOTE` : `onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"` for example : `onesignal_google_project_number: "5454545845"` <=== Your sender ID.

[image]

[image]

Comment: App id is same as i placed in the project.